# Using a regular expression to replace everything between tags contained within XML output

Tags: regex, plsql

I've been trawling the internet trying to find a solution to this issue. Basically I am using a web service provided by the company that runs our support software to retrieve customer tickets and output them (dependent on filtering) through our system so that customers can see from their dashboard which current support tickets they have active. I've managed to get the desired tags from the XML that is returned via the web service and place their content in a html table (therefore listing the active tickets row by row in the table) however, as the ticket description tag is populated with the content from emails sent by clients, there is lots of nasty redundant css and styling that has been applied to the Email that I would like to remove.

So far I have managed to use the 'replace' function to replace some of the redundant content from this email content ->

```
        l_html_build := replace(l_html_build,'&lt;','<');
        l_html_build := replace(l_html_build,'&gt;','>');
        l_html_build := replace(l_html_build,'&amp;lt;','');
        l_html_build := replace(l_html_build,'&amp;gt;','');
        l_html_build := replace(l_html_build,'&amp;nbsp;','&nbsp;');
```

However I now need to overwrite the p tags which have all sorts of garbage added to them so that they just become standard p tags->

```
    From this:
    <p 0in;&quot;="" 3.0pt="" padding:="" 1.0pt;="" solid="" border-top:="" none;="" _mce_style=""border:" 0in&quot;="" 0in="" 1.0pt;padding:3.0pt="" #b5c4df="" style=""border:none;border-top:solid">

    To this:
    <p>
```

I've looked into using the regEXP function listed here [psoug](http://psoug.org/snippet/Regular-Expressions--REGEXP_REPLACE_882.htm) however this appears to require a select statement that is performed each time. The data I need to manipulate is stored in a CLOB called l_html_build so is there any way of adapting the regEXP function to be used in a similar way to the replace function above or is there an alternative method that I am not aware of?

I apologise if this is a noob question. My expertise lies in front end development, PHP and MySQL but unfortunately I'm now required to bits of PL/SQL in my new role.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knowing that:

- There is no standard PL/SQL package that parses HTML.
- [You can't reliably parse HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Furthermore, Oracle only support basic regular expressions, restricting its capabilities.
- You want to stay in PL/SQL

You are left with few options (that I can think of):

1. Write a simple procedure yourself that will work in most of the cases (but there will be many exceptions that will break your parser).
2. Use a java parser, load class in database, call java from PL/SQL. Oracle comes with its integrated jvm, so this involves no extra setup.

I would go with option (2) if you want reliability, or option (1) if infrequent but inevitable losses are acceptable.

---

Since your content will be coming from email client, we can assume that only a tiny (negligible?) fraction will have very obscure HTML.

In that case you could start with simple regex expressions that may need some tweaking:

```
SQL> SELECT regexp_replace(
  2  '<p1 3.0pt="" padding:="" #b5c4df="">
  3  text
  4  </p>',
  5                        '<([[:alpha:]]+)[^>]*>',
  6                        '<\1>') remove_attr_simple
  7    FROM dual;

REMOVE_ATTR_SIMPLE
------------------
<p>
text
</p>
```

This will fail to catch tricky valid HTML (such as `<P attr=">">`) but since your input is somewhat standard this should be fine often enough. You may need to remove HTML comments with another procedure -- I'm not sure it can be done with regex.

Comment: Hi Vincent, Thanks for your response. As this is just a small starter PL/SQL project for me within the company (as I'm generally in charge of the website development rather than the product) the use of Java in this case may be overkill although I really appreciate your response. Ideally all I want to do is remove everything from the p tag apart from the p itself which I thought could easily be acheived using something like regexp_replace(l_html_build,<p[:alnum:]>,<p>) but looking at it I'm going to run into trouble with > " and other characters. This is why I hate and generally avoid regexp.

Comment: See my updated answer (that probably needs some further tweaking :)

Comment: Thanks Vincent. Is there a way of running this without performing the select on dual (E.g. similar structure to the replace statements I have used above?).

Comment: Of course, if you're working in PLSQL just use standard assignation: `variable := regexp_replace(...);`

Comment: Sorry, i'm struggling to understand how it would be converted. regexp_replace(l_html_build,'<([[:alpha:]]+)[^>]+>','<\1>') remove_attr_simple) ? Would this not remove the <p> from the p tag also?

Comment: I've just tried it and unfortunately it doesn't work correctly. It appears to remove the final character from all of my tags :-S

Comment: @jezzipin yes it may need some tweaking =), I've replaced it with `'<([[:alpha:]]+)[^>]*>'`

Answer (score 1):

SQL is really not the best tool for this job.  Nor will regexes be able to perform this kind of task reliably.  You would be better off extracting the data and processing it in another language using an XML parser.

Presumably Oracle itself is not sending these emails.  What program does the sending, and can you add some programmatic processing at that point?

Since you already know PHP, [here is a discussion of parsing HTML/XML in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3577641/1919238).  Similar tools are available in most other languages.

Comment: This is not an option. Our entire system is written in PL/SQL hence why this must be done in PL/SQL. The emails are sent via whatever the user wishes to use (Outlook etc.) and are managed in a ticketing system which we are calling as a web service. If I could do this in PHP I'd have done it already but thanks for the link (which still makes interesting reading).